# How to view pending changes on an SQL transaction?

Tags: .net, vb.net, t-sql

While working on some functions that update my database, I was writing some quick tests just to make sure my functions were executing properly.  When it comes time to actually update the database I can pass a transaction to a function and then commit it:

```
user.Assignment("assignment value for some column in table", connection, transaction)
transaction.Commit()
```

I am curious if there is a way to write a quick test that can verify that the transaction will actually update certain rows before committing?

(pseudoish-code)

```
user.Assignment("assignment value for some column in table", connection, transaction)
If Not transaction["SomeColumn"] = "Expected value for SomeColumn"
    assert("ColumnName was not going to be updated to the expected value!")
transaction.Rollback()
```

Comment: keep your transactions short/fast, do your checking when/before you do the modifications and NOT after, use OUTPUT to return any changes if you really need them.

Comment: I do all of that already.  This isn't really a question of what to do in practice, but more so if it is possible at all.  What is "OUTPUT"?

Comment: If you are still inside the transaction, you *should* just be able to query it...?

Comment: @MarcGravell - after talking with my Senior DBA, you are totally correct, but I cannot select a comment as a correct answer :(

Comment: My assumption was that you wanted to look from another application / connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you are inside the connection, you can just query the data like you would normally; *other* callers will be blocked, but you will have full access to the modified data.

If you are using `TransactionScope`, this means you can just use any command/connection (to the same database) as long as that connection is created inside the `TransactionScope` - it will automatically enlist to the transaction (although using the *same* connection instance is more efficient - avoids any risk of jumping to DTC).

If you are using `DbTransaction` you will have to use the same connection instance, and remember to set the `.Transaction` appropriately on any commands you execute against the connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the values by selecting them using `with (nolock)` from SSMS.  If you'd like to view this from .NET, I believe you can change the isolation level and re-query.

Comment: So, if I update some columns related to the transaction, those values will be reflected in the table before the commit?

Comment: I'm not certain of this but you may also need to turn MARS on or use another thread to do this from a client

Comment: @afuzzyllama That's the whole reason to use transactions.  You're writing it to the database uncommitted.  You can read uncommitted transactions by changing your isolation level - which is what NOLOCK does.